# package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-65-generic is not ready for configuration cannot configure (current status `half-installed')

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

Since I have trouble updating my system using Software Updater (it always tells me the `/boot` is not large enough), I have opted to update using the terminal. So far, until this evening, the terminal way has worked great. First I did

```
$ sudo aptitude autoclean
```

which worked great. Then I did

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

which (today) returned the following errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch
http://www.linuxtrack.eu/repositories/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources
404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch
http://www.linuxtrack.eu/repositories/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch
http://www.linuxtrack.eu/repositories/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
ones used instead.
```

Which is odd because I know "LinuxTrack" is a head-tracking program used with Flight simulation programs, **and I don't have any installed**, and LinuxTrack is NOT installed either.

Then, during a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` in the terminal, I get the following errors:

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-65-generic (--configure):
 package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-65-generic is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-65-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

First I tried the following (I saw how some other users tried these with success):

```
$ sudo dpkg --clear-avail
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

But they didn't seem to help because I get the same error code stated above. I checked the file `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and found the `linux-image-extra-3.19.0-65-generic` and right after there is another `linux-image-extra-3.19.0-68-generic` file listed, so I'm thinking the 3.19.0-65 is an older version???

What's going on and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error on the top is not generally fatal (just for the given repository), it means that apt cannot retrieve anything from the repository website (got 404). Maybe the repo have changed the URL or have a local problem (right now there is no /ubuntu/ on linuxtrack.eu).

Half-installed is a pretty bad shape for a package, try to manually reinstall by

```
dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-extra-3.19.0-65-generic*deb
```

Comment: Currently, "linuxtrack.eu" redirects to **"https://github.com/uglyDwarf/linuxtrack"**. Down at the bottom of the page it shows another link for DOWNLOADS - **"https://github.com/uglyDwarf/linuxtrack/wiki/Downloads"**. 
This appears to be an archive for a now defunct website.